# Debugging WP7 Crash

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, crash, stack-trace

my first forray into Stack traces for WP7.

This is causing me particular trouble and is popping up from several users of my app. I need a bit of help deciphering this.

This is the stack track:

```
Frame    Image                 Function                                                                              Offset    
0        coredll.dll           xxx_RaiseException                                                                32        
1        mscoree3_7.dll    WatsonUnhandledManagedException                                                   300       
2        mscoree3_7.dll    Dbg_NotifyManagedException                                                        136       
3        mscoree3_7.dll    FirstPassException                                                                1044      
4                          TransitionStub                                                                    0         
5                          System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException                                         52        
6                          System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert                                    344       
7                          System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Add                             92        
8                          traffic_and_travel_uk.Services.push_settings.button4_Click                        92        
9                          System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick                             132       
10                         System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick                                            120       
11                         System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp                 228       
12                         System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp                               100       
13                         MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent                                                  800       
14       mscoree3_7.dll    IL_CallManaged                                                                    860       
15       mscoree3_7.dll    IL_CallDelegateInternal                                                           176       
16       mscoree3_7.dll    makeComPlusCall                                                                   984       
17       mscoree3_7.dll    makeComPlusCallReturnInt                                                          40        
   18                                                                                                           0         
19       agcore.dll        CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent                                                      400       
20       npctrl.dll        CommonBrowserHost::CLR_FireEvent                                                  36        
21       npctrl.dll        CControlBase::ScriptCallback                                                      536       
22       npctrl.dll        CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback                                                  300       
23       npctrl.dll        CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage                                712       
  24       npctrl.dll        CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc                                                        408       
25       coredll.dll       SendMessageW                                                                      96        
26       npctrl.dll        CXcpBrowserHost::SyncScriptCallbackRequest                                        196       
27       agcore.dll        CEventManager::RaiseControlEvents                                                 208       
28       agcore.dll        CEventManager::Raise                                                              320       
29       agcore.dll        CEventManager::RaiseInterleavedRoutedEvents                                       360       
30       agcore.dll        CInputManager::InterleaveMouseAndGesture                                          320       
31       agcore.dll        CInputManager::ProcessMouseInput                                                  1768      
32       agcore.dll        CInputManager::SimulateMouse                                                      248       
33       agcore.dll        CInputManager::ProcessGestureInput                                                4492      
34       agcore.dll        CInputManager::ProcessInput                                                       440       
35       agcore.dll        CCoreServices::ProcessInput                                                       68        
36       npctrl.dll        CXcpBrowserHost::HandleInputMessage                                               920       
37       npctrl.dll        CXcpControl::OnGestureEvent                                                       460       
38       npctrl.dll        CXcpControl::ProcessWindowMessage                                                 1868      
39       npctrl.dll        ATL::CWindowImplBaseT_ATL::CWindow,ATL::CWinTraits_1442840576,0_ _::WindowProc    140       
40       coredll.dll       DispatchMessageW   
41       TaskHost.exe      CHostActiveXModule::RunMessageLoop                                                424       
 42       TaskHost.exe      ATL::CAtlExeModuleT_CHostActiveXModule_::Run                                      40        
43       TaskHost.exe      WinMain                                                                           1420      
44       TaskHost.exe      WinMainCRTStartupHelper                                                           60        
45       coredll.dll       MainThreadBaseFunc                                                                428
```

So I can see its getting stuck on button4_Click function and adding the Iso storage setting, but what else is going on here? I cant understand what is causing the crash for  some people.

This is the code in question:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Add("FirstPush", "true");

        var hide = Visibility.Collapsed;
        grid4.Visibility = hide;
        SE_service_btn_Click1();
    }
```

Thanks. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for `IsolatedStorageSettings.Add()`:

```
ArgumentException   key already exists in the dictionary.
```

Use `IsolatedStorageSettings["FirstPush"] = "true"` instead. That will either create or update the key if it already exists without throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks alot, I guess this could be it. apart from the exception being above the IsoStorage line in the stack, what tells you the exception is caused by IsoStorage?

Comment: Well, the documentation for that method explicitly states that it throws that exception in the event that the key already exists and you're not checking to see if the key exists before writing to it. I would guess that your app crashes with the same exception consistently on the second push of that button :-)